# Angular 2 application on mobile browser (sleep detection)

Tags: javascript, android, angular

After mobile phone puts the browser to sleep, and stays like that for a longer period of time, after wake up it displays wrong data, which otherwise perfectly updates all the data on the page. Is there a way to detect wake up event and what's the best Angular way to reload page/component in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload your app by simply calling JS function

```
location.reload()
```

or if you want a more Angular style approach you can try calling your 
route again

```
this.router.navigate(["myRoute"]);
```

Regarding sleep on mobile browsers you can check out [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js) maybe it can serve your purpose.

Comment: Pls mark reply as answer so others know when they look at this issue.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to achieve this could be run a timer to detect if the browser is asleep.

Using RxJS timeinterval operator,

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeinterval.html

```
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).timeInterval().subscribe(timer => {
    if (timer.interval > (1000 + SLEEP_THRESHOLD)) {
        console.log ('wake-up from sleep detected');
    }
});
```

Other simple way could be,

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
setInterval (function () {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - now) > SLEEP_THRESHOLD) {
        console.log ('wake-up from sleep detected');
    }
    now = new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So basically, with Observable example, if SLEEP_THRESHOLD is 4000 after 5 sec at sleep it will log? Is that the idea or am I missing something?
And this should be done on component initialization?

Comment: The idea is, if the browser is asleep the timer will not run. When the browser is awake, and the timer runs, it will see a large difference in the duration of events emitted which should be considered as a wake-up from sleep.